# Create unique number by adding date and range of numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to take the last two digits of the created_at year and include a number on the end to get a unique number, which saves into my database.

For example, the year this year (2018) and the number 1 would produce 1801. If 1801 exists, then create 1802 and so forth. I would also require the count to reset for the following year (2019), i.e. 1901.

I'm getting the following error:

```
can't convert Range into Integer
```

**Model**

```
before_create :create_unique_number

  def create_unique_number
    loop do
      self. unique_number = (created_at.strftime("%y")).concat(sprintf '%02d', (1..100))
      break unless self.class.exists?(:unique_number => unique_number)
    end
  end
```

Comment: what if the record is more then 100 , then your 1801 become 1901 . is it correct ?

Comment: No. It would be more than 100. If it was it would be 18101.

Comment: Sorry, but its not logical way.

Comment: This sounds incredibly inefficient. You’re considering doing potentially 100 sql queries (`select 1 as one from table_name where unique_number = some_value;`) inside of a database transaction. That’s just asking for a deadlock. Why not just use `SecureRandom.uuid` instead? It’s literally made for building random unique ids. If your column is actually a number currently, you’ll have to change it to a string. You’ll still need to do your exists check loop, but your chance of a collision will be substantially lower. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

Comment: Also, don’t forget to put a unique index on this column. Exists checks do not account for race conditions (multithreaded environments) and in the real world are not good enough.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I did have self. unique_number = (created_at.strftime("%y")).concat(sprintf '%02d', SecureRandom.random_number(100)). But was hoping to do it in order 1..100